# How can I resize the table view in a UITableView controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, sdk, tableview

I have a `UINavigationController` that contains the view of a `UITableViewController`. How can I resize the table view from within the navigation controller?

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for but its sounds close enough. This will resize your tableView to whatever pixel size you specify. It will do it in a transition too (so it doesnt just jump to size). You can remove the transition if you wanted.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];

CGRect rect = myTableView.frame;
rect.size.height = 400;
rect.size.width = 300;
myTableView.frame = rect;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: this is the exact code I am using to resize my tableview within my app. Not sure why yours wouldnt be working.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[self tableView] setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this method will help you to resize the table rows:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```